# How can I extract the inner string elements from a json using python?

Tags: python, json, structure

I have this weird raw JSON input :

```
{
"URL_IN": "http://localhost/",
"DownloadData": "{\"data\":[{samples:[{t:1586826385724,v:5.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1},{t:1587576460460,v:0.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1}]}]}"
}
```

And I want to access and extract the inner elements, like `t`, `v` from samples using Python.

Comment: You want value of t,v... ,right?

Comment: Yes @VishalUpadhyay

Answer (score 1):

You can first clean json using `regex`. For cleaning i am splitting json into two parts `url_data and download_data` .

First step remove the unnecessary double quotes from `download_data` this regular expression `re.sub('"', '', data[data.index(',') + 1 :])` removes the double quotes.

Next add the double quotes to words using regular expression `re.sub("(\w+):", r'"\1":',  download_data)` this will add double quotes around all the words in the json.

```
import re
import json
data = '{"URL_IN": "http://localhost/","DownloadData": "{\"data\":[{samples:[{t:1586826385724,v:5.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1},{t:1587576460460,v:0.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1}]}]}"}'
url_data = data[:data.index(',') + 1]
download_data = re.sub('"', '', data[data.index(',') + 1 :])
data = url_data + re.sub("(\w+):", r'"\1":',  download_data)
data = json.loads(data)
res = [(x['t'], x['v']) for x in data['DownloadData']['data'][0]['samples']]
t, v = map(list, zip(*res))
print(t, v)
```

**Output:**

```
[1586826385724, 1587576460460] [5.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: That's perfect ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here the main problem what I saw is the value in `DownloadData` is not in json format, so you need to make it as json.

**Code**

```
a={ "URL_IN": "http://localhost/", "DownloadData": "{\"data\":[{samples:[{t:1586826385724,v:5.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1},{t:1587576460460,v:0.000e+000,l:0,s:-1,V:-1}]}]}" }
i = a['DownloadData']
#converting string to json
i = i.replace("{",'{"').replace("}",'"}').replace(":",'":"').replace(",",'","')
i = i.replace("\"\"",'\"').replace("\"[",'[').replace("\"]",']').replace("\"{",'{').replace("\"}",'}')
i = i.replace("}]}]}","\"}]}]}")
i = i.replace("}\"","\"}")
final_dictionary = json.loads(i) 
for k in final_dictionary['data'][0]['samples']:
    print("t = ",k['t'])
    print("v = ",k['v'])
    print("l = ",k['l'])
    print("s = ",k['s'])
    print("V = ",k['V'])

    print("###############")
```

**Output**

```
t =  1586826385724
v =  5.000e+000
l =  0
s =  -1
V =  -1
###############
t =  1587576460460
v =  0.000e+000
l =  0
s =  -1
V =  -1
###############
```

Comment: Hey Vishal! Thanks for the solution. Yes the problem was the json was not clean enough to work directly.